# Yii2 URL rule - passing parameter based on pattern

Tags: routes, yii2

I have a controller/action: `site/signup` That takes parameter `campaign`

My rule is:

```
[
    'pattern' => '<controller>/<action>',
    'route' => '<controller>/<action>',
    'suffix' => '.html'
]
```

My action definition is:

```
public function actionSignup($package = 'trial', $campaign = null, $invite = null){}
```

What I want to achieve is to create URL alias as such:

```
http://something.com/twitter
```

That would open `site/signup` with `$campaign = 'twitter'`

I thought this rule would work:

```
'twitter' => 'site/signup<campaign:twitter>'
```

But unfortunately it doesn't. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Damn, managed to solve it right after posting question...

Its quite obvious really:

```
<campaign> => 'site/signup'
```